# Checking if a built in method in JS is called

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if `Object.assign` is called on my object, and if that is falsy I do some further work on the object. How do I do this? My code looks like this:

```
if (Object.assign) {... }
```

Comment: That cannot be your code, `if (Object.assign)` will always evaluate to true because `Object.assign` is a function which is not being called.

Comment: To find out if a property has been modified on an object, you should use a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy and trap its `set` operations

Comment: Your code checks if the method exists *(or at least if the property has a truthy value)*. Not sure what you mean by *"...is called on my object"*.

Comment: I smell an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you share more background about the problem? Why would detecting `Object.assign` calls work for you?

Comment: I want to stop object.assign to being called on the object :)

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg You cannot stop `Object.assign` from working just on your object.

Comment: Are you only trying to detect `Object.assign`, or also other ways that can alter your object? Do you want to avoid modifications permanently, or only temporarily? You want to avoid assigning a specific property, or all kinds of properties?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid modifications permanently on everything assign do at the object @oriol

Comment: Only `Object.assign`? But allow `object.property = value` and `Object.defineProperty`?

Comment: Yeah or in general, say if I call Reflect.ownKeys, I'd want to prevent that

Comment: I don't see the relation between `Reflect.ownKeys` and preventing assignments

Comment: Preventing methods being called? It is pretty straight forward really haha

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg: You still haven't told us *why* you would want to do that. Preventing builtin-methods from being called at all will in general break the whole environment.

Comment: @Bergi Hey! Yeah, sorry, I'm bad at questions. I just want to know how to prevent built inn methods and play around with it

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg: Well just overwrite it with a function that does nothing (`Object.assign = o => o;`) and you've successfully prevented its usage. If not just playing around but looking for serious scenarios, try using `Object.freeze` or `Object.preventExtensions` on your object.

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign just copies properties over to an object. To find out if a property is being set, you can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) . You can't prevent `Object.assign` from working only on your object. You can either:

- Override `Object.assign` so it doesn't set properties (bad idea)
- Prevent everyone from setting some properties on your obect (maybe closer to what you want)

```js
let validator = {
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    console.log('an attempt to set values has been made', obj, prop, value);
    // The default behavior to store the value
    obj[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
};

let person = new Proxy({}, validator);

Object.assign(person, {a: 2});
```

> I want to stop object.assign to being called on the object

Here's a hack I really don't recommend

```js
var objectThatCannotBeObjectAssigned = {a:1};


var oldAssign = Object.assign;
Object.assign = function(target) {
  if (target === objectThatCannotBeObjectAssigned) {
     return target;
  }
  return oldAssign.apply(this, arguments);
}

console.log(Object.assign(objectThatCannotBeObjectAssigned, {a: 2}) );


console.log(Object.assign({a:1}, {a: 2}));
```

Comment: if I want to intercept a function/method that only checks existing values, how would I do that instead?

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg Your questions need more code, you are asking questions that are too open ended and frankly don't make sense. Ask a question that shows exactly what code you are trying to get working.

Comment: Just trying to get it from different angles. Say if I do Reflect.ownKeys, how would I stop that from being called?

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg You can override native functions, not really recommended unless you really know what you are doing. Put up an example

Comment: Through Proxies then? @Juan Mendes

Comment: Mind giving me a hint Juan?